# How to import datepicker into SQL request?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, datepicker

This is the SQL request that I use so I can pull today's records ,

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM pb_stats WHERE DATE(time)=DATE(now())";`

but I want to pull from yesterday , 7 days back or this month , last month , even choose a custom range .

I have a script - datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    </head>

   <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
</script>
```

How to configure the SQL request use the date range from the datepicker ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use DATE_SUB or DATEDIFF or CURRENT_DATE etc.

here is a use of DATE_SUB
Example : DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL, expression, UNIT)
DEMO    : DATE_SUB(  '2016-12-25', INTERVAL 3 DAY )

and Please visit this 
https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/date-lastweek.php

Comment: If I use this it will be static but I want to chose the date or date interval from the datepicker  jquery